# Re-install system ruby after "gem update --system" borked it

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

In attempting to update something else, I ran "gem update --system" (something I don't usually do) and it ended up not quite finishing successfully. Now when I run any gem command or even ruby, I get an error that ends with:

```
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/defaults.rb:23:in `default_spec_cache_dir': undefined method `user_home' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Attempting to use rbenv to reinstall v. 2.6.4 of ruby ultimately fails with

```
1: from /Users/john_muccigrosso/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/path_support.rb:75:in `default_path'
```

No idea where to go now. Suggestions very welcome!

Comment: Reinstall your OS, which will reinstall your system Ruby. Then never do that again.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I just did a re-install from the recovery partition. Still having trouble finding the user_home, according to the error.

Answer (score 0):

While the system reinstall didn't work on its own, I was able to get things working again. I attempted to uninstall 2.6.4 via rbenv and resulted in a bunch of permission errors, which made me think that perhaps the `gem update --system` command had changed some or all of them and that was causing the problem. So I removed the 2.6.4 directory completely (well, moved it so that I could recover anything from it) and did a reinstall of 2.6.4 via rbenv. Voila!

All seems well right now.